# Missing permissions error while trying to fetch ads data using API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

We have an App that is connected to several advertising accounts. In the past, we used to use the app internally by our developers to fetch the ads data and use it internally for monitoring analysing purposes. We used to face some token expirations issues from time to time (we use long living user token) but we refresh the token and our job is able to refresh the token.

However, in the last month, our token is expired, and when we refresh the token and we try to fetch the data, we get the error: `"(#100) Missing permissions"`.

```
Status:  400
  Response:
    {
      "error": {
        "message": "(#100) Missing permissions",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 100,
        "fbtrace_id": "-"
      }
    }
```

Despite that the permissions we are giving to our app are: read_insights, ads_management, ads_read, public_profile, and in the past used to work fine, but suddenly it's not working anymore.

We did some investigations, we found a lot of issues like those, but we couldn't find a solution. Also, our app is used internally within the company, by developers to fetch Ads data. Are we missing anything here? Can submitting an app review be a solution for the problem?

Comment: I'd start by debugging the token, to see what permissions it _actually_ encompasses.

Comment: How to do that? the console is showing only the shared message

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The debug is showing that the token is granted the permission I gave it to it. Also for all the permissions `pages_show_list, ads_management, ads_read, business_management, pages_read_engagement` it shows `Applies to all objects`. Also the token is valid for 2 months. Not sure where the issue is

Comment: What specific API request throws this erro?

Comment: I'm trying to get the ads insights `AdAccount.APIRequestGetInsights` from the ad accounts